# Python extracting item from sublist into variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

Im trying to take use certain items in this sublists and use it in a if statement it doesn't want to work its probably oblivious just cant seem to find anything on it

```
path = [['Start', 'Centre', 2], ['East', 3, 2], ['West', 6, 3], ['North', 1, 1]]
x = path[0]
if x == 'Start':
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access elements of sublist like below:

```
path = [['Start', 'Centre', 2], ['East', 3, 2], ['West', 6, 3], ['North', 1, 1]]
x = path[0][0]
if x == 'Start':
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `for` loop to identify all sublists satisfying your criterion. Here we wrap it in a generator expression to keep it lazy:

```
path = [['Start', 'Centre', 2], ['East', 3, 2], ['West', 6, 3], ['North', 1, 1]]

for value in (var for var, *others in path if var == 'Start'):
    print(value)

# Start
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a list. You probably meant to use `x[0]` i.e. the first element of that list.

```
path = [['Start', 'Centre', 2], ['East', 3, 2], ['West', 6, 3], ['North', 1, 1]]
x = path[0]
if x[0] == 'Start':
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem you could have easily solved by yourself just inspecting the value of `path[0]` in your python shell:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> path = [['Start', 'Centre', 2], ['East', 3, 2], ['West', 6, 3], ['North', 1, 1]]
>>> x = path[0]
>>> x
['Start', 'Centre', 2]
```

You can see that - suprise - `path[0]` is a `list`, so obviously it cannot compare equal with a string. The string you're looking for is the first in `x`, so it's `x[0]`:

```
>>> x[0] == "Start"
True
```

Actually just looking the definition of `path` was enough to find this out - it's a list of lists, so  `path[0]` is a list, obviously ;-)